# Is there a way for to make a histogram that goes from 0-180 go 30-180/0-30?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a histogram that has values that range from 0-180 (angles) but since it's representative of half vectors 0 and 180 degrees, therefore 30 and 210 degrees are the same thing in this context. I was wondering if there was a way for my plot to go from 30-180/0-30 since the distribution is centered better like that.

This is the code I'm using where PolAngWest has just a bunch of values ranging from 0-180.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.xlabel('Number of Angles',fontsize='20')
plt.ylabel('Angles',fontsize='20')
plt.title('Angle Distribution (West of object)',fontsize='30')
nAng35,binsAng35,patchesAng35 = plt.hist(PolAngWest,10)
```

Comment: Seems like it would make the most sense to go from 30-210 than 30-180/0-30. But to do what you want you would need to create two distinct graphs and link them together. Here's an example of a broken axis: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be to use numpy's `np.histogram()` to calculate the bar values, and then use `plt.bar()` to show the bars.

The example uses `barh` to create horizontal bars, to make the bars coincide with the labels for the x and y axes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

PolAngWest = np.random.uniform(0, 180, 200)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.xlabel('Number of Angles', fontsize='20')
plt.ylabel('Angles', fontsize='20')
plt.title('Angle Distribution (West of object)', fontsize='30')
bin_boundaries = np.arange(0, 181, 10)  # make sure there is a boundary at 30
bin_texts = [f'{b0:.0f}-{b1:.0f}' for b0, b1 in zip(bin_boundaries[:-1], bin_boundaries[1:])]
bin_values, _ = np.histogram(PolAngWest, bins=bin_boundaries)
plt.barh(bin_texts[3:] + bin_texts[:3], np.concatenate([bin_values[3:], bin_values[:3]]))
plt.margins(y=0.01) # less whitespace near the bars
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with 0-30 and 30-180 separated]

Optionally, you could add a line to separate the two parts.

A simpler approach uses `np.where()` to convert the range 0-180 to 30-210. Again, using a horizontal histogram to match the x and y labels. For comparison, the same bins are used as in the previous example, but here you could also just set `bins=10`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

PolAngWest = np.random.uniform(0, 180, 200)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.xlabel('Number of Angles', fontsize='20')
plt.ylabel('Angles', fontsize='20')
plt.title('Angle Distribution (West of object)', fontsize='30')

bin_boundaries = np.arange(30, 211, 10)
plt.hist(np.where(PolAngWest < 30, PolAngWest + 180, PolAngWest), bins=bin_boundaries, orientation='horizontal',
         ec='white')
plt.margins(y=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.hist using np.where to change the angles]